# How to compare value in list without using loop in python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a list l with sorted number, for example,

```
[1, 5, 6, 9, 14, 19]
```

And I'm trying to find if a given number is between two numbers in the list.

For example, if a number 12 is given, then I want to get 9 and 14 since 12 is between them.

I wrote this using a for loop,

```
l = [1, 5, 6, 9, 14, 19]
n = 12
for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    if n >= l[i] and n < l[i + 1]:
        print(str(n) + " between " + str(l[i]) + " and " + str(l[i + 1]))
```

However, if this loop is inside another loop and has a very big list, this could be slow. Is there any way to do this without using a loop? For example, using numpy because I know it's strong dealing with array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(l,n)
out = np.take(l,[idx-1,idx])
```

Comment: The np.searchsorted algorithm uses a binary search, so it will get the job done in log(n) time.

Comment: @cameronroytaylor Yeah AFAIK, it follows the same philosophy as bisect module for searching.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yeah if the number to be searched is already the minimum/first number. The expected behavior isn't listed, so I guess I will let OP take a call on how to handle such corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bisect` native python module.

It uses dichotomic algorithm to find insertion index in the list so it is very fast (`log(n)` instead of n). Beside, on popular platforms (linux, windows, ...) it has a native implementation: unbeatable.

Then report the value at this index and the next, to say which numbers it was between.

Small example with various in and out of range values. I used such a method to solve a knapsack problem and it was very efficient.

```
# use bisect because the list is known to be sorted
from bisect import bisect

def test(value, l):
    idx = bisect(l, value)    
    # if idx is inside the list, we have a definite find
    if 0 < idx < len(l):
        return (l[idx-1], l[idx])
    # check for boundary condition error
    elif len(l) == idx and value == l[-1]:
        return (l[-2], l[-1])
    else:
        return None

def print_formatted_result(value, result):
    if result is None:      
        print (str(value) + " was not found")
    else:
        print (str(value) + " between " + str(result[0])+ " and " + str(result[1]))

z = [1, 5, 6, 9, 14, 19]
for searched in [0, 1, 9, 12, 19, 50]:
    result = test(searched, z)
    print_formatted_result(searched, result)
```

output:

```
0 was not found
1 between 1 and 5
9 between 9 and 14
12 between 9 and 14
19 between 14 and 19
50 was not found
```

Note that the original code did not find 19, but this code reports it as a special case. All other cases match the same as the original code.

Comment: The requested format would have been more like position = bisect(listname, value); if 0 < position < len(listname): print "formatted between message"

Comment: pos can be 0 if searched == 1

Comment: mine would have python2 style print. I'll do that

Comment: I note that my code has the exact same boundary condition issue as the original problem.  It finds l[0] but not l[-1]. We'll assume that was an error and find it, but otherwise the OP finds l[idx], l[idx+1]

Comment: thanks, I have accepted your edit as-is even if it has been heavily modified because it fixes the last item issue so 1) it is tested and 2) it is better than my code